# Hiking with a medium sized dog (German Spitz)

Tags: dogs, outdoor

We are thinking of getting a German Spitz. Just want to double check that this breed will be able to get conditioned to long hikes 15-20km. Perhaps longer on vacations (30km+).

Articles I found so far are written by people doing 5-10km hikes

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I found two sites in German language, which state that the Spitz is in general a dog, who has fun to move. One speaks about around 2 hours walks weekly and whole days of hiking at vacations. But they differ between the three sizes (Kleinspitz, Mittelspitz, Grossspitz).

Comment: https://www.baak-dogwalker.de/weblog/55-hunde-dieser-welt-der-spitz

Comment: https://www.spitz-info.de/forum/index.php?thread/6909-wie-lang-kann-ein-kleinspitz-laufen/